# Installing ubuntu from customized live CD

Tags: boot, live-cd, kickstart

So basically I modified an installation iso file. To be specific I added a kickstart file to it to automate the installation of ubuntu 14.04.1 i386, I modified the isolinux/txt.cfg file to make it use the kickstart file.

Now, to test the installation-script I started a virtual machine and booted the disc image. A lot of text popped up, checking the state of the machine. I quess the installation begins with casper, since that is the first thing that is clearly readable. Unfortunately it seems to check its file system on the floppy drive and gets stuck there, it repeatedly prints:

```
/init: line 7: can't open /dev/sr1: No medium found
```

Eventually it stops and I find myself in the BusyBox.

On [launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/500822/) people seemed to fix this problem by disabling the floppy drive.
Occasionally it didn't work for me, or I did it wrong.

My question is now: Is this a bug in casper or did I just fail to configure kickseed properly?

-- I should note, that I'm new to ubuntu and have basically no idea regarding partitioning in kickstart, might there be the problem?

ks.cfg located in /

```
#
#Generic Kickstart template for Ubuntu
#Platform: x86 and x86-64
#

#System language
lang en_US

#Language modules to install
langsupport en_US

#System keyboard
keyboard us

#System mouse
mouse

#System timezone
timezone Europe/Vienna

#Root password
rootpw --disabled

#Initial user (user with sudo capabilities) 
user ubuntu --fullname "abc" --password abc

#Reboot after installation
reboot

#Use text mode install
text

#Install OS instead of upgrade
install

#Installation media
cdrom
#nfs --server=server.com --dir=/path/to/ubuntu/

#System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr 

#Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr yes

#Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel 

#Basic disk partition
part / --fstype ext4 --size 1 --grow --asprimary 
part swap --size 1024 
part /boot --fstype ext4 --size 256 --asprimary

#System authorization infomation
auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5 

#Network information
network --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0

#Firewall configuration
firewall --disabled --trust=eth0 --ssh 

#Do not configure the X Window System
skipx
```

txt.cfg located in /isolinux

```
default autoinstall
label autoinstall
  menu label ^Automatically Install Ubuntu
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz ks=cdrom/ks.cfg –
```

Answer (score 0):

I once had this problem when trying to boot Kubuntu from USB. I used the following workaround:

1. Create Lubuntu disk and boot it (which surprisingly worked)
2. Install Lubuntu and reboot
3. Go to TTY1 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and login
4. Stop LightDM (`sudo service lightdm stop`) - just to be sure
5. Remove LXDE desktop: `sudo apt-get purge lubuntu-desktop`
6. Install KDE desktop: `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`
7. Remove packages remaining from LXDE: `sudo apt-get autoremove`
8. Reboot if there aren't any errors

I then had a stable, working Kubuntu on a system which was unable to boot from the kubuntu-13.10-i386 ISO.

You could give it a try, and use `ubuntu-desktop` instead of `kubuntu-desktop`, or whatever flavor you prefer. You could even try to automate this process in your script.